# Android PhoneGap app using jQuery $get not consistently working

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

Long story short my app is setting up an interval to get the current location every 20 seconds

```
var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true
};
gpsStatus = 0;
timmer = window.setInterval(function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
}, 20000);
```

On success it calls this function that uploads the location to a php page using $get

```
function onSuccess(position) {
    setResults(position.coords.latitude + '/' + position.coords.longitude + ' ' + new Date(position.timestamp).toLocaleTimeString().split(" ")[0]);
    $.get("http://www.mysite.com/geolog.php", { status: "READY", team: myTeam, location: position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude })
    .done(function (data) {
        setResults("Data Pushed");
    });
};
```

The geolocation is working but the get only seems to work on some devices...

I have the following in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

And the following in my config.xml

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
```

I also tried to add an iframe pointing to google just to check if it was a network issue and it's also not working, I don't know if they are related.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed to whitelist yoursite:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: in the cordova example every domain is allowed, but it doesn't work for me :/ 
$.get("http://mysite.de/search.php", {art: searchTerm, lang: language}).done(function(data){
alert("data: "+data); })